# ui_component form custom tab attribute

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, customer-attribute, tabs

I have created a **custom customer attribute** that is shown in the tab with all the general information when you **edit the customer**.

Now I need to get that attribute inside a **custom tab** that I have created.

The attribute is created with an **InstallData script** as a Customer attribute.
The custom tab is created with adding **`customer_form.xml`** `ui_component` and adding a new **fieldset** inside that.

I just need to move the field from the **general tab** to that **custom tab**
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please just provide a snap of that what you achieved & what is remaining you want to do.

Comment: Add more information.

Comment: I already figured this out. Thanks anyways. I will post the solution when i have the time.

Comment: @CompactCode Hi, did you manage to find a solution to this? I've got the exact same problem at the moment.

Comment: Hello David. I had found a solution but i would not see it as ideal. What i did (would need to look up the code since it has been a year but if you need it i can search for it) is not including the field within any tab and manually create a tab with that field.